# Grounding two boards connected to a backplane

Tags: pcb-design, grounding

I have a design which consists of a backplane and two boards mounted to this through some headers. The backplane provides a common 5V and ground to both boards and it also has a solid ground plane. Between the two boards there are two SPI buses running at ~25MHz where the connection goes from one board -> down in the backplane -> up to the other board.

Here's a simple illustration of the setup:

[image: A simple illustration of the setup]

My question is how I should handle the grounding between the boards at the data connector. The alternatives I have come up with are:

1. Connect the gnd in both data connectors to the common ground plane on the backplane
2. Only connect gnd in data connector 1 to gnd in data connector 2 and don't connect to the ground plane
3. Don't use a gnd connection for the data connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a great situation because in any of these three cases there will be a potential issue:

1. Ground loop. If there is any differential between the ground of one card to the other at the backplane (connector resistance, trace resistance, especially with large static or dynamic current) you will get current flow through the data connector grounds.
2. Forcing the ground path through the backplane. This is a good way to induce magnetic emission because that is based on the loop area.
3. Same issue as 2, but with less immunity to external noise.

Any one of these might work fine, especially if you don't have to pass a compliance test (ie some one-off test gear) and don't need to worry too much about emissions in your setup.

A possible alternative would be to pass the power and data to PCB #2 via PCB #1. This would have the benefit of reducing loop areas and keeping potentials down.

Another alternative would be to isolate the SPI signal with a suitably-rated optocoupler, but that is pretty extreme.

Finally, you might turn it into a differential pair, which would have the benefit of reducing the dynamic current being transferred. This would make option 2 more reasonable.

Keep in mind that grounding and EMI/EMC is a complex issue, and a final solution will depend a lot on enclosures, cable routing, bypassing, and other factors.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had my suspicions that none of the solutions were optimal and your explanations make sense. I had thought of converting the SPI to differential as you mentioned and think this is the way I will go. One of the boards has an FPGA so differential should work just fine with some extra drivers and receiver on the other board.